# Cant remember the author or title sci fi space portal planet colonization

Tags: story-identification

Cant remember the name if a sci fi book i tead it was based around the invention of a space portal where it closes the distance between two spots (space portal ) built from one end used for planet exploration . Books prologue is the last pilot if a space shuttle finally landing in mars just to come face to face with what he discribed as two surfer dudes standing in caltech when one of them say hey dude ! Which turned out to be the first test try if the device it thn gies on to years later wen one scientist on a planet far from earth notices a star appearing in the sky so travels through a space portal which have been used for cars appearing as tunnels to the onlookers from one end to a planet light years closer and double checks and is right a new star appared so thn trVels light tears further away farther past his original planet cliser to earth and reports it to his collegues and its the start to a mission to investigate the new star n ut turns it was an two entire star systems had been enclosed in a visible shield odd some sort and the star appearing was the first going down they couldnt see in but after sending probes and investigative waves the shield is dropped revealing an entire star system colonized by a  species of sentient species so unique and complex i cant describe thm but they had been enclosed in Ahield was would soon be realised for the universes good . I’ve missed out loads of main details so al give a quick list memory was stored on crystal chips and if death occured an insurance company would commission a clone if that person and the memory uploaded continuing life so humans are technically immortal 
one of the creators of the portal end up lost on a supernatural trek travelling planets by unknown nature trails that jump planets without them knowing where or how 
the other species captured one of the original investigation crew members an astrologist the one who saw the star appear infact sorry just remembered prior to the crew giong there they loaded there memorys n were told if caught by anything hit the data wipe on the memory as it was an implant controlled with the mind witha screen appearing with a eye implant and the species get his knowledge of what he knows including the basica of portal technology this species is cerg advanced and had xolonised every meteor or small planet in there enclsure thathad the space or mined for resources

Comment: This could use serious editing if you want anyone to read and make sense of it -- at the least, try to fix the spelling, punctuation, and break it into paragraphs.  No one will read a "wall of text", hence you'll get no answers.

Comment: Before you look for answers, Brian, buddy, I'd suggest you to edit your question to make it clearer. It has severe formatting and break-up problems. I can hardly even make out where a sentence ends.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SFF! As other have said can you [edit] your question to be more readable. You also might benefit from reading [this guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question/9337#9337) and adding any other details you remember into your question.

Comment: Almost certainly this is it, but we don't officially mark as a duplicate until the OP confirms, but I believe you are looking for Pandora's Star (book one of the Commonwealth Saga) by Peter F. Hamilton.

Comment: I can see that the text is a mess sorry this is the first time i’ve used one of these sites.That is exactly the book i am looking for thank you.